# How to display the text in single quote data in xml tag using sed

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have used following code to extract data file and try to append to existing xml tag using 
  sed but it's not return the values for a, b and c.

```
while read -r a b c ; do
  cat xml | sed '\|<entry>| a <test_id>${a}</test_id> ' >> xml_out.xml
  cat xml | sed '\|<entry>| a <test_case>${b}</test_case> ' >>xml_out.xml
  cat xml | sed '\|<entry>| a <region>${c}</region> ' >>xml_out.xml
done < input_data.dat

a) Input data(input_data.dat)
   12123 'QA test case 1' 'QA environment'   
   12234 'UAT test case 1' 'UAT environment'
```

b) xml (Input file 
     
        2014-05-28T19:10:00-07:00 
        1000573988

```
<entry> 
    <updated>2014-05-28T19:10:00-07:00</updated> 
    <id>1000573988</id> 
</entry> 


Expected output(xml_out.xml) 
(after append xml file)

<entry>
    <test_id>12123</test_id>    
    <test_case>QA test case 1</test_case> 
    <region>QA environment</region>
    <updated>2014-05-28T19:10:00-07:00</updated> 
    <id>1000573988</id> 
</entry>
<entry> 
    <test_id>12234</test_id>    
    <test_case>UAT test case 1</test_case> 
    <region>UAT environment</region> 
    <updated>2014-05-28T19:10:00-07:00</updated> 
    <id>1000573988</id> 
</entry>
```

Comment: You should have *six* output entries, not two, and there will be no indentation on the <test_id> <test_case> and <region> tags.  Also, the "read" command does not do quoting.  Also, "sed" takes a file name argument, rendering the "cat" command superfluous.

Comment: The general purpose UNIX tool to process text files is awk. To do what you want would be a small simple awk script but you haven't described the problem well enough for someone else to provide the solution. Get the book "Effective Awk Programming, Third Edition" by Arnold Robbins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your input data fields are separated by commas (as in the second line you displayed) and there are no commas other than those, you could do something like this:

```
IFS=,  # set the input field separator to a comma
while read -r a b c ; do
  b=${b//\'/}    # remove the single quotes from the string
  c=${c//\'/}    # ditto
  sed '\|<entry>| a <test_id>${a}</test_id> ' xml >> xml_out.xml
  sed '\|<entry>| a <test_case>${b}</test_case> ' xml >>xml_out.xml
  sed '\|<entry>| a <region>${c}</region> ' xml >>xml_out.xml
done < input_data.dat
```

Answer (score 0):

My *guess* is that this is what is really wanted:

```
IFS=','
while read -r a b c ; do
  b=${b//\'/}
  c=${c//\'/}
  sed '\|<entry>| a \
    '"<test_id>${a}</test_id>\\
    <test_case>${b}</test_case>\\
    <region>${c}</region>" xml
done > xml_out.xml << _EOF_
   12123,'QA test case 1','QA environment'
   12234,'UAT test case 1','UAT environment'
_EOF_
cat xml_out.xml
```

Well, when I run it:

```
$ cat sh.sh ; echo ;bash ./sh.sh
# set -x
IFS=','
while read -r a b c ; do
  b=${b//\'/}
  c=${c//\'/}
  sed '\|<entry>| a \
    '"<test_id>${a}</test_id>\\
    <test_case>${b}</test_case>\\
    <region>${c}</region>" xml
done > xml_out.xml <<- _EOF_
    12123,'QA test case 1','QA environment'
    12234,'UAT test case 1','UAT environment'
    _EOF_
cat xml_out.xml

<entry>
    <test_id>12123</test_id>
    <test_case>QA test case 1</test_case>
    <region>QA environment   </region>
    <test>QA test case 1</test>
    <updated>2014-05-28T19:10:00-07:00</updated>
    <id>1000573988</id>
</entry>
<entry>
    <test_id>12234</test_id>
    <test_case>UAT test case 1</test_case>
    <region>UAT environment</region>
    <test>QA test case 1</test>
    <updated>2014-05-28T19:10:00-07:00</updated>
    <id>1000573988</id>
</entry>
```

There is still polishing to do, but that is really an "exercise for the reader".

Comment: I don't have comma in the input file

Comment: If it is a nuisance to parse file, then you can do it the hard way:  read line ; a=${line%%\'*} ; line=${line#$a} ; b=${line#*\'} ; .....

Comment: I have converted input file into comma separated but still give some error as input file not recognized.